# who determines whether should ping send a ARP request?

Tags: ipv4, tcp, tcpdump

In my Fedora linux, My eno1's ip is `192.168.1.105` and my gateway's ip is `192.168.1.1`, and netmask `netmask 255.255.255.0`

For monitoring ARP request, in one terminal, I used `sudo tcpdump -i eno1 -v "icmp or arp"`, in another terminal, I run the `ping 192.168.1.5`(not exist) or `ping 192.168.91.1`:

When I `ping 192.168.1.5`, which is not existed in my LAN, in the `tcpdump` terminal, I got the `ARP` request:

```
 [abelard@localhost iputils]$ sudo tcpdump -i eno1 -v "icmp or arp"
 [sudo] password for abelard: 
 tcpdump: listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
 06:39:13.111379 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has     192.168.1.5 tell localhost.localdomain, length 28
```

When I `ping 192.168.91.5`, which is still not existed in my LAN, in the `tcpdump` terminal, I did not get the `ARP` request:

```
 [abelard@localhost iputils]$ sudo tcpdump -i eno1 -v "icmp or arp"
 tcpdump: listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
 06:50:02.417926 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 32986, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
localhost.localdomain > 192.168.91.1: ICMP echo request, id 6682, seq 1, length 64
 06:50:03.417060 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 33783, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
localhost.localdomain > 192.168.91.1: ICMP echo request, id 6682, seq 2, length 64
```

I want to know who determines to send `ARP` request or not to send `ARP` request?
The some googled results said this is done by linux kernel, if yes, I want to know where in linux kernel?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host OSes are off-topic here. Each OS can do things differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A host that needs to send something to another host on the LAN needs to *resolve* the layer-3 (e.g. IP) address to the layer-2 (e.g. ethernet) address. That is what ARP (Address *Resolution* Protocol) does.

A host will maintain an ARP table in which it can look up a layer-3 address to resolve to the corresponding layer-2 address. If the layer-3 address is not in the ARP table, then the host broadcasts an ARP request to get the necessary information.

Comment: why there is no `ARP` request when I ping `192.168.91.1` (my eno1's ip 192.168.1.1)?

Comment: Because that layer-3 address is probably already in the ARP table.

Comment: Thank you! there is no `192.168.91.1`  in ARP table, this is relative to [Anding process](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/understanding-and-performing-ipv4-subnetting/) , In this page, you find the sub title "Finding the subnet address"

Comment: But, the layer-3 address to which the traffic must be sent is in the ARP table. It is just the layer-3 address of the configured gateway. Layer-2 addresses are only significant on the LAN, and any address not on the LAN uses the address of the configured gateway.

Comment: who detect the address(here 192.168.91.1) is not LAN address?

Comment: The host itself know which addresses are on its network, and which are not. That is basic IP. With a mask, or mask length, you can determine if two addresses are on the same network. A host is configured with an address and mask, so it can determine if any other address is on its network.

Comment: "The host" you should mean some one program or process? When ping running, the program will be triggered? what's name the program?

Comment: It is the network stack of the OS. OSes and applications are off-topic here. It's not just ping, but _any_ traffic that needs to be delivered on a layer-2 protocol that uses MAC addresses.

Comment: As you know, where to ask "the network stack of the OS"? I am reading the network stack code, but I don't know where it is implemented!

Answer (score 6):

What happens is

1. Ping builds a ping packet and passes it to the kernel.
2. The kernel looks up the destination in the routing table. Based on the routing table it determines an interface and a "next hop IP address".
3. If the interface is "Ethernet like" the kernel looks up the next hop IP address in the ARP table for the interface.
4. If there is an entry in the ARP table the kernel attaches the MAC addresses to the packet and sends it. Otherwise it puts it in a queue and sends out an ARP request.

You do not say what your subnet mask is but I will assume it is 255.255.255.0

> ping 192.168.1.5

1. Ping generates a packet destined for 192.168.1.5
2. The kernel looks up the destination in the routing table. The packet matches the implicit route created by setting the subnet mask. This tells it that the destination is "on link" on eth0. Since the destination is on-link the next hop IP address is the same as the destination address.
3. The kernel looks up the next hop in the arp table for eth0. It finds no entry.
4. The kernel sends out an arp request.

> ping 192.168.91.5

1. Ping generates a packet destined for 192.168.91.5
2. The kernel looks up the destination in the routing table. The packet matches the default route (aka the default gateway). The next hop IP address is 192.168.1.1
3. The kernel looks up 192.168.1.1 in the arp table and most likely finds a match (you tend to talk to your default gateway quite a lot).
4. The ping gets sent.

Sorry I don't know the exact layout of the code in the linux kernel to tell you where the code implementing this is.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Green's answer is correct and comprehensive.

I want to point out why there is no `ARP` request when you ping `192.168.91.1`.

#### High-Level

Because the subnet mask is `255.255.255.0` and your IP is `192.168.1.105`, the protocol stack recognizes that `192.168.91.1` is not in the same subnet as yourself. Thus it determines that the next-hop IP is the first-hop router IP `192.168.1.1`. Then it resolves the MAC address of `192.168.1.1`, which most likely has been in the ARP table, since you frequently send packets to the first-hop router.

#### Concretely

The kernel looks up the destination `192.168.91.1` in the routing table(`netstat -r` or `route`). Which should look like:

| Destination | Gateway | Genmask | Iface |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | 192.168.1.1 | 0.0.0.0 | eno1 |
| 192.168.1.0 | * | 255.255.255.0 | eno1 |

Note:

- `*` might be `0.0.0.0` for some versions of `netstat`.
- `default` and `*` will be `0.0.0.0` for `netstat -rn` or `route -n`.
- Windows `netstat -r` or `route PRINT` will show `On-link` instead of `*`.

`netstat` and `route` is deprecated, `ip route` will show routing table in another format looks like:

> default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1
>
> 192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.105

The kernel finds that `192.168.91.1` doesn't match `192.168.1.0/24` or `192.168.1.0 Genmask 255.255.255.0`, so it uses `default` entry and resolves the next-hop IP to `192.168.1.1`.